# React Hooks useState() with Object TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't find the solution to this error in my code every time I try to type something in my input field. TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

but I've done like the answer in the following post https://stackoverflow.com/a/57519847/16568705 still not work

Here is all code

**MultiStepForm.js**

```
import { useForm, useStep } from "react-hooks-helper";
import React from "react";
import { LaporanPolisi } from "./stepForm/LaporanPolisi";
const defaultData = {
    laporanPolisi: {
        nomorLp: "",
        jenisKelamin: 0,
        tanggalLp: "",
        kerugian: 0,
        uraianSingkat: "",
        pasalDilanggar: [
            {
                undangUndang: "",
                pasal: ""
            }
        ]
    },
    pelapor: [],
    saksi: [],
    korban: [],
    terlapor: [],
    barangBukti: [],
    tkp: {
        kodeProvinsi: "",
        kodeKabupaten: "",
        kodeKecamatan: "",
        kodeKelurahan: "",
        kodeRT: "",
        kodeRW: ""
    }
}
const steps = [
    { id: "laporanPolisi" },
    { id: "pelapor" },
    { id: "saksi" },
    { id: "korban" },
    { id: "terlapor" },
    { id: "barangBukti" },
    { id: "tkp" },
    { id: "submit" }
]
export const MultiStepForm = () => {
    const [formData, setForm] = useForm(defaultData);
    const { step, navigation } = useStep({
        steps,
        initialStep: 0,
    });

    const props = { formData, setForm, navigation };

    switch (step.id) {
        case "laporanPolisi":
            return <LaporanPolisi {...props} />;
        case "pelapor":
            return "Pelapor";
        case "saksi":
            return "Saksi";
        case "korban":
            return "Korban";
        case "terlapor":
            return "Terlapor";
        case "barangBukti":
            return "Barang Bukti";
        case "tkp":
            return "TKP";
        case "submit":
            return "Submit";
        default:
            return <LaporanPolisi {...props} />;
    }
};
```

**LaporanPolisi.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export const LaporanPolisi = ({ formData, setForm, navigation }) => {
    const {
        laporanPolisi
    } = formData;
    const handleChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        console.log(name)
        setForm(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            laporanPolisi: {
                ...prevState.laporanPolisi,
                [name]: value
            }
        }));
    };
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header">
                <h4>Laporan Polisi</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="nomorLp">Nomor Laporan</label>
                            <input onChange={handleChange} id="nomorLp"
                                placeholder="Nomor Laporan" type="text" className="form-control" name="nomorLp" value={laporanPolisi.nomorLp} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="jenisKelamin">Jenis Kelamin</label>
                            <select onChange={handleChange} value={laporanPolisi.jenisKelamin} id="jenisKelamin" name="jenisKelamin" className="custom-select">
                                <option value={0}>Laki-Laki</option>
                                <option value={1}>Perempuan</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/* <input placeholder="Tanggal Laporan" type="text" className="form-control" name="nomorLp" value={jenisKelamin}></input>
                    <input placeholder="Kerugian" type="text" className="form-control" name="nomorLp" value={nomorLp}></input>
                    <input placeholder="Uraian Singkat" type="text" className="form-control" name="nomorLp" value={nomorLp}></input>
                    <input placeholder="Nomor Laporan" type="text" className="form-control" name="nomorLp" value={nomorLp}></input> */}
                </div>
            </div>
            <pre>
                <code>
                    {JSON.stringify(formData.laporanPolisi)}
                </code>
            </pre>
        </div>
    )
}
```

error Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Gjf.jpg
thanks before sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Check if `event.target` is actually an `element` or it's `undefined`

Comment: Please, specify usage of which of the fields leads to the error.

Comment: hello mr @MNNTNK this is my picture showing the console log
https://imgur.com/cbb0jnp
https://imgur.com/VhSpzIr
https://imgur.com/8gQMQtl
thanks for answering my question

Comment: hello mr @OlegKurbatov , the error show when i input some text  and showing typeError cannot read property 'name', this is the image :
https://imgur.com/lqA7sv3
https://imgur.com/tFDfYgM
https://imgur.com/Krhm0cC
https://imgur.com/r8EF672
https://imgur.com/GIOTt8f
thanks for answering my question sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved
i need to define name like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvwIZ.jpg
in section Nested Object at https://github.com/revelcw/react-hooks-helper
and then, this is my fullcode after change:
**LaporanPolisi.js**

```
import React from 'react';
export const LaporanPolisi = ({ formData, setForm, navigation }) => {
    const {
        laporanPolisi
    } = formData;

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    };
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header">
                <h4>Laporan Polisi</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="nomorLp">Nomor Laporan</label>
                                <input onChange={setForm} id="nomorLp"
                                    placeholder="Nomor Laporan" type="text" className="form-control" name="laporanPolisi.nomorLp" value={laporanPolisi.nomorLp} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="jenisKelamin">Jenis Kelamin</label>
                                <select onChange={setForm} id="jenisKelamin" name="laporanPolisi.jenisKelamin" className="custom-select" value={laporanPolisi.jenisKelamin}>
                                    <option value={0}>Laki-Laki</option>
                                    <option value={1}>Perempuan</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => navigation.previous()} type="button">Previous</button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => navigation.next()} type="button">Next</button>
                        </div>
                        {/* <input placeholder="Tanggal Laporan" type="text" className="form-control" name="nomorLp" value={jenisKelamin}></input>
                    <input placeholder="Kerugian" type="text" className="form-control" name="nomorLp" value={nomorLp}></input>
                    <input placeholder="Uraian Singkat" type="text" className="form-control" name="nomorLp" value={nomorLp}></input>
                    <input placeholder="Nomor Laporan" type="text" className="form-control" name="nomorLp" value={nomorLp}></input> */}
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <pre>
                <code>
                    {JSON.stringify(laporanPolisi)}
                </code>
            </pre>
        </div>
    )
}
```

thanks everyone for answering my question

Answer (score 0):

All react components have to return a component, for example: ...

In your `MultiStepForm.js` there are only 2 cases meet this requirement.

And this is the way I dealt with input, if you want to update `setForm`, you can add it in `hanldeChange`:

```js
export default function BasicExample({ formData, setForm, navigation }) {
  const [input1, setInput1] =useState(''); 
  const [input2, setInput2] =useState(''); 

  const handleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
        console.log(input1)
        console.log(input2)
    };
  return (

    <form onSubmit={handleChange}>
    <div className="col-md-6">
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="nomorLp">Nomor Laporan</label>
            <input onChange={e => setInput1(e.target.value)} id="nomorLp"
                placeholder="Nomor Laporan" type="text" className="form-control" name="nomorLp" value={input1} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-6">
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="jenisKelamin">Jenis Kelamin</label>
            <select onChange={e => setInput2(e.target.value)} value={input2} id="jenisKelamin" name="jenisKelamin" className="custom-select">
                <option value={0}>Laki-Laki</option>
                <option value={1}>Perempuan</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
      <button type="submit"> Summit</button>
  </form>

  );
}
```

Comment: i have to implement the return component but still not work, can u suggest different answer? thanks for helping me

Comment: nws, I have updated solution, check if it works

Comment: thanks sir, i resolve this error when i read the docs of the module in Nest Object Section at https://github.com/revelcw/react-hooks-helper
thanks for answering my question